# how do we decide where roots get sent when constructing Galois group automorphisms?

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose we have the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]2, i)$.  In this problem:

[Find Galois group and all intermediate fields of the extension $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)\supseteq \mathbb{Q}=K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606606/find-galois-group-and-all-intermediate-fields-of-the-extension-l-mathbbq-sq?rq=1&newreg=f3fd51cd190f4fb7bc329b7ac3a80bc3)

It is shown that the group will be determined by the automorphisms $\sigma( i)$ and $\sigma(\sqrt[4]2)$.  It says that $\sigma( i) \in \{i, -i\}$ and $\sigma(\sqrt[4]2) \in \{\sqrt[4]2, -\sqrt[4]2, i\sqrt[4]2, -i\sqrt[4]2\}$

I'm aware that roots must get sent to roots.  I see how $i$ can go to $i$ or $-i$, but why is $i\sqrt[4]2$ a possibility for $\sqrt[4]2$?  And why isn't $\sqrt[4]{2^2}$ or $\sqrt[4]{2^3}$?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ is $x^4-2$.  What are its roots?  Does that answer your question regarding $\sqrt[4]{2^2}$ and $\sqrt[4]{2^3}$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Thank you.  I was using what I knew about roots of unity, which clearly does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest polynomial of over $\mathbb Q$ that $\sqrt[4]{2}$ satisfies that we can immediately think of is $x^4-2$ and by Eisenstein's criterion, this is irreducible. So we should expect $\sqrt[4]{2}$ to have four conjugates and how do we get them? We multiply $\sqrt[4]{2}$ by the four numbers which are invariant under taking a fourth power, namely $1,i,-1,-i$.

Answer (score 0):

By "roots get sent to roots," one means that "$a$, having minimal polynomial $f$, gets sent to a root of $f$"

*Proof*: let $\phi$ be a field homomorphism $K\to L$ and let $x\in K$ have min poly $f\in K[t]$. We can lift $\phi$ to a map $K[t]\to L[t]$ in the natural way and find that as $0=f(x)$, $0=\phi(f(x))=\phi(f)(\phi(x))$ so the min poly of $\phi(x)$ divides $\phi(f)$. Now suppose $\phi$ is an automorphism: $K=L$ and let $L\ni x\ne0$. Then as all field homomorphisms are injective, $\phi(x) \ne0$ (so long as $x\ne 0$) and so it can't have min poly 1. $K$ is a field so $K[t]$ is a UFD so irreducibles are prime and so $\phi(x)$ has the same min poly as $x$.

Consider whether the numbers you suggested are roots of the minimal poly of $^4\sqrt 2$ over $\mathbb Q(i)$ (and hence roots of all polys over that field which have $^4\sqrt 2$ as a root)

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following theorem (sometimes called "Artin's Extension Theorem").

---

Let $\sigma:K \to K'$ be an isomorphism of fields and let $L/K$ and $L'/K'$ be extensions.

Suppose $\alpha \in L$ is algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomial $P \in K[X].$

Then for each root $\beta$ of $\sigma(P)$ in $L'$, there is a unique homomorphism of fields

$$\tau:K(\alpha)\to L$$

such that $\tau|_K=\sigma$ and $\tau(\alpha)=\beta.$

---

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i).$

The minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $X^2+1,$ which has exactly two roots in $L,$ namely $i$ and $-i.$

Hence, by the theorem, there are exactly two field homomorphisms

$$\sigma_j:K\to L \; \; \; (j=1,2)$$

where $\sigma_1(i)=i$ and $\sigma_2(i)=-i$ and both restrict to the identity on $\mathbb{Q}.$

Observe that the image of both $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ is $K\subseteq L$ and so by restricting the codomain we have

$$\sigma_j:K\xrightarrow{\sim} K \subseteq L \; \; \; (j=1,2).$$

The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $K$ is $X^4-2$ and we have $\sigma_1(P)=\sigma_2(P)=P.$

Observe that $L$ contains exactly 4 roots of $X^4-2,$ namely $\sqrt[4]{2},\,i\sqrt[4]{2},\,-\sqrt[4]{2},\,-i\sqrt[4]{2}.$

Applying the theorem again shows that, for each $j=1,2,$ there are exactly 4 field homomorphisms

$$\tau:L=K(\sqrt[4]{2})\to L$$

such that $\tau|_K=\sigma_j.$

Since $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite extension every homomorphism $L\to L$ is an automorphism.

Thus we have found all the automorphisms of $L/\mathbb{Q}.$